# Symfony 2 Form error "This form should not contain extra fields." when submitting a form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sylius, php-5.6

I am submitting a form and handling it in the Sylius `ResourceController` which submits the form and validates it.

This is the form in situ:

```
<tr>
   <form method="post" action="{{ path('backend_course_row_update', {
 'courseeId' : course.id, 'id' : row.id }) }}" novalidate>
     {{ form_widget(form.channel) }}
     {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
     {% for size in form.sizes %}
        {{ form_row(size) }}
     {% endfor %}
     {{ form_row(form._token) }}
     <td align="right" style="width: 140px;">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>Save
         </button>
     </td>
  </form>
</tr>
```

The "form" here is a `CourseGuideRowType`, which looks like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('channel', 'channel_choice', array(
            'required'    => false
        ))
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('sizes', 'course_guide_row_sizes', array('numColumns' => $options['numColumns']))
    ;
}
```

`CourseGuideRowSizesType` then looks like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $options['numColumns']; $i++) {
        $builder->add($i, 'text', array('required' => 'false'));
    }
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            for ($i = 0; $i < $options['numColumns']; $i++) {
                if (empty($form->get($i)->getData())) {
                    $form->remove($i, 'text');
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

However, when I submit the form and dump out the errors like this:

`$form->submit($request, !$request->isMethod('PATCH'))->getErrors()`

I get:

```
"This form should not contain extra fields."
      #messageParameters: array:1 [▼
        "{{ extra_fields }}" => "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
      ]
        -extraData: array:6 [▼
          0 => "36"
          1 => "38"
          2 => "40"
          3 => "42"
          4 => "44"
          5 => "46"
        ]
```

The "extra data" is the "sizes" fields.

Am I doing something blatantly wrong here?

**EDIT June 2017: You can now use 'allow_extra_fields' to suppress this error. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields**

Comment: Normally the error is thrown when user submitted data has more inputs than are defined in the form. Symfony has a built in type which already does what you are trying to do manually: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html .

Comment: Also not the best solution, but you can also allow extra fields by setting `'allow_extra_fields' => true` on option resolver.

Comment: Note: allow_extra_fields option has been added in Symfony v2.6

Comment: @Munir Yes, you're right. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is thrown because you are defining each `size` as a `form_row`, e.g. :

```
{% for size in form.sizes %}
    {{ form_row(size) }}  // Extra field defined here
 {% endfor %}
```

As stated in comments, you should use the [CollectionType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) or create and use your custom FormType in the same way of it.

This will avoid the need for manually defining extra fields in your form and BTW remove the error.

**EDIT**

@nakashu has reminded a workaround to be used at the moment.

Just avoid the error by adding the following in your `CourseGuideRowType`:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'allow_extra_fields' => true,
    ));
}
```

But it doesn't make you free of side effects during the handling/binding steps.